# Having trouble translating this: 多是不跑步的替跑步的操心

Tags: translation

My rough translation is "better not to run than to run and worry about it." It's the double 的 and 替 that's throwing me off. Is my translation close?

Here's the context:

最令人啼笑皆非的是，有关这事的争吵，多是不跑步的替跑步的操心。至于说，顶着雾霾跑马拉松会形成不良的示范，更是无稽之谈

It's the second to last paragraph in the article below:

http://news.ifeng.com/a/20141020/42245256_0.shtml

Comment: 替某人操心：worry about someone, => many who are not running worry about those who do/ those not running are more likely to worry about those who run,怎么样？

Comment: @S.Rhee Make that an answer?

Comment: 已经太晚了，会给分配比下面回复要晚的时间标记／too late, will be given time mark later than answer below

Comment: 关于＂多是＂请参考爱词霸同n词库／for ＂多是＂ see iciba，nciku

Comment: entering "替 操心" into iciba leads to  5 example sentences 4 of which translate it as "worry about", one as "concerned about". Strangely this is followed by  "替某人操心  bother for sb， but without example sentences，nciku has １example sentence： 别替他操心了。Don't worry about him.

Comment: S.Rhee - thanks. If I could give you more rep points, I would.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not quite; I break this fragment like this:

- 多是
- 不跑步的
- 替...操心
- 跑步的

The word "多是" is a bit tricky too, as in this case it's an abbreviation of "[大多](http://baike.baidu.com/view/3134962.htm)是", or "mostly is".

So altogether, it should be:

> , mostly is those who don't run worrying on behalf of those who run.

Of course, this direct translation is awkward, so it might be better to rephrase it according to the preceding fragments. Here's my crude attempt:

> What's most laughable about all this hullabaloo, is that it is mostly coming from non-runners worrying about runners on their behalf.

Comment: Thanks for the 替...操心 pattern. It's not in "330 Common Chinese Patterns". Wondering if there is a more comprehensive listing of patterns anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a chinese, only know a little of English.

有关这事的争吵，多是不跑步的替跑步的操心。

can be explained as(not translated):

```
The people who argued that haze(雾霾) may hurts the marathon runer's health is mostly  the poeple who didn't took part in the marathon.(The implication was that: the marathon runer may not care about the haze.)
```